When playing solo, why do some players seem to be in cahoots in Brawl Stars?
This happens fairly often and I see it almost ever other game, which is beyond weird. In the solo game mode every player is supposed to be for themself, but I often see a very strange situation where 2 (and very occasionally more) players seem to be working together. Sometimes they even have the same brawler and/or matching skins/names. They often ambush other players, ganging up on other people. This really takes a lot of people by surprise and thus they get jumped and killed very quickly and effectively, because normally you don't expect to see people working together in "Solo".
When players like these meet they don't attack each other. They literally just walk past each other or spin together tauntingly in a coordinated fashion, just short of high fiving each other. I have also seen these players spin/dance together mockingly after they coordinated a surprise attack to which I sadly fell prey. In another solo game it came down to three players including me. When the other two players ganged up on me and finished me off, one of them, who had fought tooth and nail against me, walked up to the other one and just stood there, basically letting themself be killed. Obvious match fixing.
How is this even possible? How do they get in the same solo game? I guess statistically it is not impossible if you try and start the game at the same time with your buddies, but I have tried that with my friends countless times but we have never successfully entered the same game even once. But what I witness is very often. And I am certain the players I played with were not bots (I know sometimes players are put in a game with bots).
Possible cheating?

As aytimothy said, it’s generally a situation that happens during a match, not before it. What you describe could be hacking or somehow manipping the matchmaker.

"Spinning" in Brawl Stars is sorta a symbol of "I'm like you; truce?"
It happens a lot because the phenomenon is well documented and known by the a large swathe of the playerbase.
They use each other to power their supers up (by attacking but not killing) each other and then team on other enemies. It's been used as a tactic used to semi-team for an advantage in what is supposed to be a solo game.

I get that, but matching names/brawlers/skins? I can't for the life of me find an explanation for that. Also the kind of match fixing I have witnessed seems beyond reason too. There's no possible way you can verbally communicate with someone you don't already know in a solo game, so I don't know if there exists any explanation for someone voluntarily getting killed in the game.

It's done because it's a well-known signal - The knowing of the signal IS the correlation; like a dog-whistle (minus the politics).

Yes I know that. That is not my question. I am talking about something else. I mean spinning can mean more than one thing and spinning as mocking is just as common if not more. Also it seems a lot of people don't think or don't know cheating and game manipulation on Brawl Stars are real. They are real. I recently reported 5 suspected cheating cases in ranked games and I later received system notifications that 3 of those cases resulted in action against those players I reported. 3 out of 5 might just be my personal exp with cheating but so far my hunch is 60% accurate.

"Also it seems a lot of people don't think or don't know cheating and game manipulation on Brawl Stars are real." | That's the point of a dog whistle :) You know; you know. You don't, well you don't.

Hmm not really though. It's actually the opposite: I am pretty sure I'm providing information here.

I was talking from everyone else's perspective. You and me already know about it and are aware. Now, you can backstab anyone who spins ;) or, spin and betray for an easy kill.
